# Can't connect to SAMBA - ISP is blocking it

Tags: firewall, router, samba, isp

Security issues aside, I'd like to connect to a SAMBA share from home to a server (dedicated or vps, doesn't matter).

The server works perfectly. The issue is on the client side. Let me more clear: the issue is my ISP!

I can access these shares even with my smartphone using 3G. When using the free WiFi offered by my ISP I have no issues as well. --> Super BAD and dangerous, I know.
Instead, my home network (WiFi or ethernet) cannot connect to the samba shares.

This what I tried:

1) Opened ports 137, 138, 139, 447 on the client (doesn't make any sense I know, these are server ports)

2) Put the client on a DMZ. Still, no results.

3) Called my ISP (VOO - Belgium), but phone operators didn't know how to help me.

---

This is the exit status I get:

```
Connection to SERVER_IP failed (Error NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT)
```

This is the command I successfully use with public WiFi, but fails with the home connection:

```
smbclient //SERVER_IP/Testing -U USER
```

Router has a simple IPv6 firewall that I disabled, no firewall on the client.

Do you know how to overcome this? I really don't want to use public WiFi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your server with SSH and make a tunnel for SMB traffic from your client to your server.

Something like:

```
ssh -L 137:127.0.0.1:137 -L 138:127.0.0.1:138 -L 139:127.0.0.1:139 -L 447:127.0.0.1:447 you@your.server.address
```

And then use:

```
smbclient //localhost/Testing -U user
```

This creates a tunnel that forwards traffic from the client computer ports 137,138,139,447 to respective server ports, and then one connects with `smbclient` to the client computer's listening port.

You can use `autossh` to make this tunnel "persistent".